# Macbook Air 13" 2015, won't return from sleep unless physically rotated

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

My girl bought a Macbook Air 13", newest generation a couple of weeks ago. It has been working flawlessly until now.

When she tried to wake it from sleep, the screen was black and didn't respond to pressing the power button, or anything. We held the power button for 10s, and nothing happened. Then I closed it, picked it up and turned it around (to check the availability to unplug the battery, to no avail). After setting it down and opening the screen, the lock screen appeared as if nothing had happened. The same thing happened after a few minutes, but then the screen returned when I just picked it up from the table.

Not having found anything on the internet (except on other person who had a similar issue, but there were no answers to his question) I suspect that maybe the screen cable has bad contact with the connector, which is improved when the computer is rotated or moved.

The Macbook hasn't sustained any impact or liquid damage.

Any ideas?

Comment: Other than exercising your warranty? Sounds like the problem is easily demonstrated.

Comment: I suppose that is the way to go in the end. The problem doesn't always occur, so I'm not sure that we will be able to demonstrate it, but I suppose they will have to take our word for it.